# NSURLConnection connectionDidFinishLoading called before all file is downloaded

Tags: iphone

I am using NSURLConnection to download a zipped file from a web service. In the didReceiveData I append the data to a file and using a good internet connection all appears to work correctly. The file is transparently unzipped as it is downloaded. 
If, however, I have a poor internet connection the connectionDidFinishLoading appears to be called before all the data has been received. Is there another delegate method that I should be trapping or some kind of timeout in NSURLConnection that is making it think that the download is finished as opposed to calling didFailWithError?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should check that the size of the received data is as expected.

the following will get you the expected size of data:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
 long long dataSize = [response expectedContentLength];
}
```

every time you get a call to didReceiveData, reduce it from the dataSize, and if you get a call to connectionDidFinishLoading and the dataSize is bigger than 0, there is a problem.

Comment: Thanks that will resolve my issue but I still don't understand why NSURLConnection thinks it has finished without error when there is clearly something wrong.

Comment: Web servers doesn't obligated to report an error on timeout, because in some cases the data you already got might be enough, and if not try again or resume from the place you stopped

Comment: Just been hit by this stupid bug. Why the hell isn't didFailWithError called? It's obviously an error!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm back on this issue because I had it too and passed a lot of time to understand what's wrong.

Apparently, I have better result (on iOS) when I use 
`[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:TRUE];`

I did a double check on the received data and relaunch the request where it stopped if didn't received all the data, with something like:

`- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)myConnection{`
`if (receivedDataSize<expectedDataSize) // protection`
    {
`[self.connection cancel];
        [self setConnection:nil];
        [self setResponseData:nil];`

`self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[myConnection originalRequest] delegate:self];

        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myConnection.originalRequest.URL
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                           timeoutInterval:kRestRequestTimeout];
        [request setHTTPMethod:myConnection.originalRequest.HTTPMethod];`

```
    // Define the bytes we wish to download. Start from where it's stopped
    NSString *range = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bytes=%i-",[[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:receivedDataSize]intValue]];
    [request setValue:range forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:TRUE];}
```

Hope it can help